# Back to previous view-sate after action state

Tags: spring-webflow

I'm using Spring webflow for my product. In current `view-state` I have a transition to a `action-state` to decide which states to go next. However, there's a case requiring to stay at current `view-state` after `action-state`. I treated it the same as other states but it caused a reload of my current page. I don't want that. Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your page reloads is normal because webflow sees this as an exit of the view-state when transitioning to the action state and a re-entry of the same view-state when leaving the action-state again. So to avoid the reload you have to avoid leaving the view-state in the first place. There are several way to do this. The simplest way I can think of is to use an EL expression to select the target state directly from the transition element, instead of putting that logic in a separate action-state:

```
<view-state id="bla">
    <transition on="submit" to="#{someAction.selectNextStateId()}" />
</view-state>
```